# Adding column in meanjs database

Tags: mongodb

the below code is the default structure of a `meanjs.org` database.  How can I add a new column like `Balance` in the mongodb?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("597695d922fa1025a453ed39"),
    "salt" : "aGHDfk3+7Bg1lR8YI2JTAg==",
    "displayName" : "sample samples",
    "provider" : "local",
    "username" : "admins",
    "created" : ISODate("2017-07-25T00:50:33.800Z"),
    "roles" : [ 
        "user"
    ],
    "profileImageURL" : "modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png",
    "password" : "McRqjKUIzslHzCrg8VLyXXQZEZS/GqQyBewvI8xgutppYGvsexcbqf/ua9foennx6xy0unRiHrVAB7T1jF2v1Q==",
    "email" : "admin@admin.com",
    "lastName" : "samples",
    "firstName" : "sample",
    "__v" : 0 }enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you showed is an example of a user saved in your MongoDB database inside User collection.

To edit the User schema in MEAN.JS you can do so by editing the file located in `/modules/users/server/models/user.server.model.js` and add the properties you need.